# how do I git merge with no fast forward in visual studio 2022?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I use --no-off git flag for with no fast forward merge how can I use no fast forward in visual studio

I use command below for this

```
git merge --no-ff feature_newfeature
```

I want use git merge with no fast forward in visual studio 2022

Comment: This is not a about `C#`, nor `.net`, nor even `git` (removed tags). I'm not even sure it belongs here, this is not a technical question about programming, but a user question about a product. Don't they have user support?

Comment: @RomainValeri quite the opposite, this is very much in scope and there are a *lot* of similar questions about IDEs and programming editors over the years. In fact, SO exists because people were frustrated with official programming support forums. You may complain that VS isn't VS Code but this is definitely a good question

Comment: @RomainValeri this was out of scope so would all the questions about VIM or even git itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That's why I commented before voting to close or downvoting or anything else. Your point seems fair, answer it to your heart's content, my friend :-)

Comment: Someone with 1.2M rep already answered for VS. VS Code is a completely different product

Comment: "Someone"? That's not "someone", that's *Le* VonC :-D

Answer (score 1):

None of the [VS2022 new features](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-new-git-features-to-visual-studio-2022/#multi-repo-branching) mentions a merge with options (like `--no-ff` or `--ff-only`)

Tickets like "[Add ff-only merge strategy](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-ff-only-merge-strategy/890728)", "[Fast forward merge in pull requests](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/pull-request-merge-option-two-way-merge-but-fast-f/767638)", "[Option to toggle between git merges with or without fast-forwarding is gone](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/option-to-toggle-between-git-merges-with-or-withou/1362673)" all illustrate the lack of such option

> Previously (VS 16.7), there was a checkbox “Commit changes after merging” when performing a git merge. This allowed for a fast-forward or no-fast-forward merge decision for every merge.

That still is not implemented.